# how to make a particular column of datagrid in flex as non sortable?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make only one of the columns of a datagrid as sortable using flex 3. but using sortableColumns all the columns change their property...any solution??

Answer (score 6):

You can use the sortable flag on the DataGridColumn:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#sortable

I'm unclear what you mean by a column changing it's property.  Sorting shouldn't change the display field of the column; although it may change the value that is displayed in the column.  Sorting a single column should always change the values of other columns. That is the nature of the dataGrid.

Comment: Saw your post after I posted my answer. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the sortable option to the DataGrid, and enable it for the DataGridColumn you want.
Once you'll do it, Only the specific column you enabled will be sortable.